# Get text on next line of value found PHP

Tags: php

I have the following text file called `people.txt` with the contents:

```
mikey.mcgurk
Boss Man

michelle.mcgurk
Boss Man 2
```

I'd like to adjust my PHP script to grab the data on the line that follows each username, so if I was searching for `mikey.mcgurk`, my script would output `Boss Man`.

**PHP:**

```
<?php //
$file = 'people.txt';
$searchfor = "mikey.mcgurk";

// the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

// get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
// escape special characters in the query
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
// finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
// search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   // write all of this to a text file
   echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
}
else{
   echo "No matches found";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare like this:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$lines = explode("\n",$contents);
for($i = 0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    if( $lines[$i] ==$searchfor ) {
        echo "Username ".$lines[$i+1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this

```
$contents = file_get_contents($file);

$contents = explode(PHP_EOL, $contents);

if(array_search($searchfor, $contents) !== false){
    echo $contents[array_search($searchfor, $contents)+1];
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, Rakesh - what a neat solution - far superior to my original version :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using regular expression you can do this by getting all lines in an array

`$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $contents);`

then get keys of results

`$keys = array_keys($lines, $pattern);`

and increment keys by 1 to get the next line

`foreach ($keys as $key) {
    echo $lines[++$key];
}`